# Error in grid.arrange - arrangeGrob() function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two plots p1 and p2 which I am trying to plot using grid.arrage. My code looks as below:

```
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2,
    top = textGrob("Distribution across each day of the week", 
    gp = gpar(fontface = "bold", cex = 1.5)),
    bottom = "Day of the week")
```

However, when I run this, I am seeing an error `"Error in arrangeGrob(...) : could not find function "textGrob"`

When I run only `grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2)`, it runs fine. But without any labels and title. However, I couldnt understand what is the problem with my code. I tried both `main=...` and as well as `top=...` Neither of them works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your code will work fine, if you add `library(grid)` - `textGrob` is a function from that package.  Example, using your code: `library(gridExtra);
library(grid) ;

grid.arrange(rectGrob(),
             top = textGrob("Distribution across each day of the week", 
                                   gp = gpar(fontface = "bold", cex = 1.5)),
             bottom="Day of the week")`

Comment: Thanks, its resolved now. Thanks to you and @lawyeR for your help!

Comment: Voting to close as a typo ,due to missed library call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two simple png files.

```
value <- c(0, 1, 20, 3, 3, 0, 0, 5, 2, 5, 2, 7)
names.arg =c("0-15","15-19","20-24","25-29","30-34",
             "35-39","40-44","45- 49","50-54","55-59","60-64","65 Jahre oder Älter")
df <- data.frame(names.arg = names.arg, value = value)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=names.arg, y=value)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
save(p1, file = "p1.png")

value2 <- c(0, 1, 20, 3, 3, 0, 0, 5, 2, 5, 2, 7)
names2 =c("0-15","15-19","20-24","25-29","30-34",
             "35-39","40-44","45- 49","50-54","55-59","60-64","65 Jahre oder Älter")
df2 <- data.frame(names = names2, value = value2)

p2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=names, y=value)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "red")
save(p2, file = "p2.png")
```

When you combine them, the `top =` and `bottom =` arguments work fine:

```
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=1, top = "Example", bottom = "Sample")
```

[image]

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENT**

Create the title outside of the `grid.arrange()` call:

```
title <- textGrob("Distribution across each day of the week", gp = gpar(fontface = "bold", cex = 1.5))
```

and revise the call:

```
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=1, top = title, bottom = "Sample")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your example. However, if I want to customize my labels - both Top and Bottom, how to do it? I was thinking textGrob would provide that flexibility. But it is not working with grid.arrage

Comment: The edit shows how to customize the Top and Bottom titles.  Have you considered accepting the answer (by clicking on the green check icon)?

Comment: Thanks @lawyeR for your response.

Comment: @lawyeR; I think your edit is the same code as in the op question, is it not? The issue was due requiring a library call to grid ,so as it stands it is not really answered.